# How to open child node on click of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I'm having a jstree(version 3.0.0). I have generated the tree with json. The tree is one level deep. It looks something like

- Parent1

  - Child1
  - Child2
- Parent2

  - Child3
  - Child4

If I click on each child, it's corresponding information is shown.

Problem:
I have no content to display for parent. So if i click on parent , its first child should automatically be selected. Is there any way to do this?

Eg: If `Parent1` is clicked, then `Child1` content should be shown and for `Parent2` , `Child3` content should be shown.

I have tried to do this using the click events and adding and removing classes, but didn't get desired result. See my code below:

```
    <div id="mytree"></div>
    <p class="hidden pele" id="dog">I'm Dog</p>
    <p class="hidden pele" id="lion">I'm Lion</p>
    <p class="hidden pele" id="mobile">I'm Mobile</p>
    <p class="hidden pele" id="lappy">I'm Lappy</p>
```

```
var arrayCollection = [
{"id": "animal", "parent": "#", "text": "Animals", "state": {"selected": true}},
{"id": "device", "parent": "#", "text": "Devices"},
{"id": "dog", "parent": "animal", "text": "Dogs"},
{"id": "lion", "parent": "animal", "text": "Lions"},
{"id": "mobile", "parent": "device", "text": "Mobile Phones"},
{"id": "lappy", "parent": "device", "text": "Laptops"},
]; 
var all_p = $('.pele');
$('#mytree').jstree({
    'core': {
        'data': arrayCollection
     }
}).on(
      "select_node.jstree", function(evt, data){
          all_p.each(function(){
              if(this.id === data.node.id){
                  $(this).removeClass('hidden');
              }else{
                  if(!$(this).hasClass('hidden')){
                       $(this).addClass('hidden');
                  }
              }
           })
 });

$("#mytree >ul >li >a").on('click', function(){
      $(this).prev('i').trigger('click');
      $(this).next('ul.jstree-children li a').toggleClass('jstree-clicked'); 
});
```

Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/khz65nv0/3/

Eg: If `Parent1` is clicked, then `Child1` content should be shown and for `Parent2` , `Child3` content should be shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if selected node is a root node then get it's first child id

```
"select_node.jstree", function(evt, data){
    let nodeid = data.node.id;

    if(data.node.parent === "#" && data.node.children_d.length > 0){
      nodeid = data.node.children_d[0]
    }
    all_p.each(function(){
        if(this.id === nodeid){
            $(this).removeClass('hidden');
        }else{
            if(!$(this).hasClass('hidden')){
                $(this).addClass('hidden');
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `changed.jstree` event. This event triggered when selection changes so just check the newly selected `aria-level` if it is `1` that means the parent node is selected and then just trigger another click to select the child.

```js
var arrayCollection = [
{"id": "animal", "parent": "#", "text": "Animals", "state": {"selected": true}},
{"id": "device", "parent": "#", "text": "Devices"},
{"id": "dog", "parent": "animal", "text": "Dogs"},
{"id": "lion", "parent": "animal", "text": "Lions"},
{"id": "mobile", "parent": "device", "text": "Mobile Phones"},
{"id": "lappy", "parent": "device", "text": "Laptops"},
]; 
var all_p = $('.pele');
$('#mytree').jstree({
    'core': {
        'data': arrayCollection
     }
}).on(
      "select_node.jstree", function(evt, data){
          all_p.each(function(){
              if(this.id === data.node.id){
                  $(this).removeClass('hidden');
              }else{
                  if(!$(this).hasClass('hidden')){
                       $(this).addClass('hidden');
                  }
              }
           })
 });

$("#mytree >ul >li >a").on('click', function(){
      $(this).prev('i').trigger('click');
      $(this).next('ul.jstree-children li a').toggleClass('jstree-clicked'); 
});

$('#mytree').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
    if ($(".jstree-clicked").parent().attr("aria-level") == 1) {
        $(".jstree-clicked").next(".jstree-children").find("a.jstree-anchor:first").click();
    }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
<div id="mytree"></div>
<p class="hidden pele" id="dog">I'm Dog</p>
<p class="hidden pele" id="lion">I'm Lion</p>
<p class="hidden pele" id="mobile">I'm Mobile</p>
<p class="hidden pele" id="lappy">I'm Lappy</p>
```